# Python - Take string generated in python shell and print TO command line interface

Tags: python, cmd, os.system

Made a python file that takes user input (messily, requires tidying up), assigns them to variables, and combines them to make a string that can be pasted in to the newly opened command line and execute another file.
I'm wondering if it is possible to take the outputted string and put it in to the command line interface without having to copy and paste the string in manually.

```
import os

labelType = input("what is the display type?(phat)")
labelColour = input("Choose a label colour: yellow, black, red")
labelPrice = input("Enter the price.")
labelName = input("Enter the name of the product.")
labelTotal = labelPrice+labelName

command = ("python labelupdate.py --type ",labelType," --colour ",labelColour," --name ",labelTotal," & pause")
commandstring = ''.join(command)
print (commandstring)

os.system('cmd /k')
```

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module to execute external commands from Python.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfamiliar with the ```subprocess``` module unfortunately, is it possible to use the string produced - it contains variables and I'm unsure of the syntax for making this work.

Comment: See `subprocess.Popen()`